# Symfony2 Extension - Behat Mink

Tags: symfony, behat, mink

I installed a Symfony2 extension for Behat Mink from [here](http://extensions.behat.org/symfony2/)
When I run test, an error occurs

> [ReflectionException] Class AppKernel does not exist.

What am I doing wrong?

**behat.yml**

```
default:
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
        base_url: http://localhost/behat
        goutte: ~
        selenium2: ~
    Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension: ~
```

Comment: Did you follow the [usage chapter](http://extensions.behat.org/symfony2/#usage) when creating your `FeatureContext`?

Answer (score 0):

First run these commands to install the dependencies:

```
composer require behat/behat
composer require behat/symfony2-extension
composer require behat/mink
composer require behat/mink-browserkit-driver
composer require behat/mink-extension
composer require behat/mink-goutte-driver
composer require behat/mink-selenium2-driver
composer require emuse/behat-html-formatter
composer require coduo/php-matcher
```

Now say your symfony applcation you want to host as localhost.behat, then add the vhost configuration to httpd_vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/behat/web"
    ServerName lochost.behat
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/behat/web">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Now your behat.yml file should be at app/config/behat.yml with belo content :

```
default:
    formatters:
        html:
            output_path: web/behat
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        # Irs\BehatPopupExtension\Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://lochost.behat/app_dev.php/
            javascript_session: selenium2
            sessions:
                symfony2:
                    symfony2: ~
                selenium2:
                    selenium2:
                        browser: chrome
        emuse\BehatHTMLFormatter\BehatHTMLFormatterExtension:
            name: html
            renderer: Twig,Behat2
            file_name: index
            print_args: true
            print_outp: true
            loop_break: true
    suites:
        api:
            type: symfony_bundle
            bundle: NameSpaceYourBundle
            #mink_session: symfony2
            mink_session: selenium2
            contexts:
                - NameSpace\YourBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext:
                    baseUrl: http://lochost.behat/app_dev.php/
                    screenCapturePath: web/behat

# Add "-p firefox" parameter to behat command to run tests with Firefox browser
firefox:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            browser_name: firefox

# Add "-p chrome" parameter to behat command to run tests with Chrome browser
chrome:
    extensions:
        #Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            browser_name: chrome

# Add "-p safari" parameter to behat command to run tests with Safari browser
safari:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            browser_name: safari
```

All you go, now add your feature and context file at namespace : NameSpace\YourBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext

and run the below commands from command prompt/git bash(preferrable):

```
bin/behat -v --suite=api @NameSpaceYourBundle/your.feature --config=app/config/behat.yml -f pretty
```

or if you want to save the output as html at web/behat directory then:

```
bin/behat -v --suite=api @NameSpaceYourBundle/your.feature --config=app/config/behat.yml
```

Let me know if it works

Note:
I am not sure if you are running selenium server or standalone server, hence adding the step to run selenium standalone server:

Download [selenium](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and place the selenium server .exe and chromedriver.exe in same folder
check with "java -version" and it should not be < 1.6.x
you may need to download compatible selenium server and chrome driver 
open command prompt and run the below commands:

```
cd C:\<folder contains selenium server .exe and chromedriver.exe>
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.0.jar
```