# When running `bin/behat` I get a "Class not found" error

Tags: behat

When I run `bin/behat` I get this error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Application' not found in 
>   /vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Console/BehatApplication.php on line 31

My composer.json file contains this:

> {
>    "require": {
>      "drupal/drupal-extension": "*",
>
>      "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable",
>      "behat/mink": "1.4@stable",
>      "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
>
>      "behat/mink-selenium-driver": "*",
>      "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*",
>
>      "behat/mink-sahi-driver": "*",
>      "behat/mink-zombie-driver": "*",
>
>      "behat/mink-extension": "*"
>    },
>    "minimum-stability": "dev",
>    "config": {
>      "bin-dir": "bin/"
>    }
>   }

And for some reason symfony/CssSelector is failing to clone:

> [RuntimeException]
>    Failed to clone via git, https and http protocols, aborting.
>
> - git://github.com/symfony/CssSelector.git
>     fatal: No such remote 'composer'
> - https://github.com/symfony/CssSelector.git
>     fatal: No such remote 'composer'
> - http://github.com/symfony/CssSelector.git
>     fatal: No such remote 'composer'

Answer (score 3):

I suggest removing `bin`, `vendor` folders and `composer.lock` file and running `php composer.phar install` again, the packages should install fine then.

Answer (score 1):

**Composer** is a only a Method for installing **Behat** you can remove Behat and try with one of following Method :

The simplest way to install Behat is through Composer.

**Method #1 (Composer)**

Create composer.json file in the project root:

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }
}
```

Then download composer.phar and run install command:

```
$ curl http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ php composer.phar install
```

Composer uses GitHub zipball service by default and this service is known for outages from time to time. If you get

The ... file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway)
during installation, just use --prefer-source option:

```
$ php composer.phar install --prefer-source
```

After that, you will be able to run Behat with:

```
$ bin/behat
```

**Method #2 (PHAR)**

Also, you can use behat phar package:

```
$ wget https://github.com/downloads/Behat/Behat/behat.phar
```

Now you can execute Behat by simply running phar archive through php:

```
$ php behat.phar
```

**Method #3 (Git)**

You can also clone the project with Git by running:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/Behat/Behat.git && cd Behat
$ git submodule update --init
```

Then download composer.phar and run install command:

```
$ wget -nc http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
$ php composer.phar install
```

After that, you will be able to run Behat with:

```
$ bin/behat
```

Answer (score 1):

try with loading --config option of behat.yml

```
bin/behat -v --config=app/config/behat.yml
```

Also not sure if you are running symfony or drupal instance.

See detail configuration of my behat+mink+selenium+symfony2.8 installation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777657/symfony2-extension-behat-mink/43871164#43871164)